# Print Out Redirect URL without Actually Redirecting

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, python, testing

I have set up a server that is a clone of our production server that we want to use as a test server for testing our redirector. Importantly, we don't want to actually redirect to these urls like we do on our production machine. Instead we just want to redirect to a page that displays in text what the url would have been.

Currently, functions exactly like the production server, i.e. it redirects you to the desired url. For reasons I won't go into, we don't want it to do this on the test server, instead we just want it display what the redirect url would have been.

The box is a fedora box, and most of the redirector scripts are written in python. Ideally, I would simply write a python script to complete this task.

Note initially, I was redirecting to a non local url. The whole function of the box was to serve as a redirector and it has no native web interface. I will have to create that web infrastructure myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just make the url that it would have went to a URL parameter of some page

ex: Instead of actually redirecting to www.website.com/page1 you would redirect to www.website.com?redirect=page1

Comment: That is exactly what I need to do. However, I am very new to this, how would I rewrite a redirect rule that achieves this function. And then how and where (I assume /var/www) would I write the page and script that prints out this param?

Comment: Note initially, I was redirecting to a non local url. The whole function of the box was to serve as a redirector.

Comment: How does that normal redirection happen?

Comment: In a .common file which delineates a set of redirect rules, for example: RewriteMap servers prg:/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.py